# Можно ли удалять вопрос и создавать его по новой?

Tags: обсуждение

Если я задал вопрос и не получил на него ответ, могу я удалить его и задать еще раз?

Comment: зачем? если вопрос плохой это не поможет

Comment: Я бы не назвал его плохим, хочу что б увидели новые люди, дополню немного, там 2 вопроса примерно об одном и том же, объединю в один

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667480/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-delphi-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9-mysql-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667357/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-tcp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-delphi-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-10-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Вы можете удалить и задать его еще раз, но после этого придет модератор и сделает вам строгое предупреждение. А при повторении ситуации - забанит.

Comment: @PashaPash да здравствует  ̶с̶у̶д̶. модератор. самый  ̶г̶у̶м̶а̶н̶н̶ы̶й̶  справедливый  ̶с̶у̶д̶  модератор в мире

Comment: @АлексейШиманский maybe вы хотите очередной раз поподбирать sha и посмотреть на еще один перебор паролей на c#?

Comment: @PashaPash разве SHA? Уже не MD5?

Comment: @D-side возможно :)

Comment: вопрос решен, так что флудить не буду